# How to display a Mayavi 3D plot inside bokeh server application

Tags: python-2.7, widget, bokeh, mayavi

I am trying to create a bokeh server application in python where I want to compute and display a 3D plot using interactive widgets and Mayavi 2. I can make the Mayavi plot show up on a standalone window. However I would rather want the plot to show embedded in a plot window inside the client webpage created by the bokeh application. Below is an example code for the bokeh server application. If the button is clicked, the Mayavi plot is created. I just want the plot to show up in the plot window right next to the button instead of a separate window. Is this possible? Thanks a lot in advance.

[image]

```html
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.io import curdoc
from bokeh.layouts import row, column, widgetbox
from bokeh.embed import notebook_div
from bokeh.models.widgets import Slider, TextInput, Button, Toggle
from mayavi import mlab
import numpy as np

# Set up plot
plot = figure(x_axis_location=None, y_axis_location=None, plot_width=400, plot_height=400, title = "3D plot", logo=None)

def MayaviPlot(attrname, old, new):
 mlab.clf()
 phi, theta = np.mgrid[0:np.pi:11j, 0:2*np.pi:11j]
 x = np.sin(phi) * np.cos(theta)
 y = np.sin(phi) * np.sin(theta)
 z = np.cos(phi)
 mlab.mesh(x, y, z)
 mlab.mesh(x, y, z, representation='wireframe', color=(0, 0, 0))
 mlab.show()


button1 = Toggle(label="Plot", button_type="success")

button1.on_change('active', MayaviPlot)

inputs = button1
outputs = plot

curdoc().add_root(row(inputs, outputs, width=1000))
curdoc().title = "Test"
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.  Bokeh only displays inside browsers. But when you run `mlab.show` that actually runs a separate executable program and there is no way to embed that inside a browser that I am aware.